# Load more maps for counter strike 1.6

Tags: counter-strike

How to add more maps to counter strike stream 1.6 ?

I am playing that on my local desktop against bots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must download the maps.  There are several good online sources for them.

To install them, follow the instructions in this [faq](http://www.cstrike-planet.com/faq/43)

Most maps you just extract in your counter strike 1.6 folder, which is located at:

> \Steam\SteamApps\ *yourusername* \counter-strike\cstrike

If the map is not packaged properly, then you'll have to place the individual files into their respective folders.

- \counter-strike\cstrike .wad
- \counter-strikee\cstrike\maps .bsp | .bsp.ztmp | .txt | .res
- \counter-strike\cstrike\sound .wav
- \counter-strike\cstrike\models .mdl
- \counter-strike\cstrike\sprites .spr
- \counter-strike\cstrike\gfx\env .tga
- \counter-strike\cstrike\overviews .bmp

Comment: This is so informative. Thanks. Let me try that. +1

Comment: Can you suggest me any good online source for MAP, I mean I really afraid of virus. So, if you could suggest me any that will be helpful.

Comment: Is these are the only maps ?http://www.cstrike-planet.com/maps

Comment: Hi Zero, yes that is a great site for maps.  You can always start another question to ask for a source for counterstrike maps as well.  I'm not too familiar with the 1.6 maps anymore and there may be people more knowledgeable in that area.

Answer (score 0):

www.gamebanana.com

This is an awesome site for customization of many PC games (CS1.6 as well).
There you can find maps, skins, sounds, and much much more.
The site itself is safe, but you have to be careful when installing any sort of custom files, especially if they are wrapped in an .exe file.
Also, you should never install .dll files because those can only be core game files and modified core files can trigger a VAC ban.

Since your original question was already answered, I thought I could answer your second question in the comments.